# Xamarin.Forms Design Start Menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]

I'm making Xamarin.Forms App.I need a design similar like this for my start menu. Any ideas,suggestions?

Comment: a TabbedPage app and the start menu a grid view with 2 columns and 4 rows

Comment: @LeoJebran some example source code?

Comment: Mind showing us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **CollectionView** . It is a flexible and performant view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications.

#### in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App10.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame Padding="10" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="120">
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                            <Image Source="{Binding BgImageSource}"  WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Frame>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

#### in code behind(or view model)

I used static data just for demo , you could replace it with your own data .

```
public class DataModel
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string BgImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

```
public ObservableCollection<DataModel> MySource { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
      InitializeComponent();


      MySource = new ObservableCollection<DateModel>() {

            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},
            new DataModel(){Title ="Transatcions" ,BgImageSource="xxx"},

       };

   BindingContext = this;

}
```

For more details and usage of CollectionView you could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/ .

Comment: i will try it and make response here

Comment: Its working now, just dont know where to add TapGesturerecognizer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Comment: @ Lucas Zhang - MSFT i found it. I have one more question. With this event i have one Command. When i click on each element navigates me to new Page. How to organize with one command this in the ModelView?

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details (like the code what you had tried ) so that I could help you better .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768384/xamarin-forms-gesturerecognizers-not-working-on-command i made new post and have a problem with the event can you see? Thanks

Comment: You could check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
-StackLayout
    -Label(Center)
    -ScrollView
        -StackLayout (Horizontal)
            -Button
            -Button
        -Grid (2 column, 4 row)
            -StackLayout
                -Image
                -Label(Center)
```

If you want to use TabbedPage, you use it.

This is work with my code https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/tabbed-view/overview

Comment: I dont need tabbedPage there will be only one menu