# Xamarin.Forms GestureRecognizers not working on Command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Code in the xaml page:

```
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">        
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MeniElementi}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="2" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame Padding="10" WidthRequest="140" HeightRequest="140">
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="120" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Image Source="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/u/5/P/D/A/arrow-50x50-md.png"  WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70"  >
                                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                     Command="{Binding LoadElements}"

                                                       />
                                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Image>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

        </StackLayout>
```

Code in xaml.cs:

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Menu: ContentPage
    {

```
    MenuViewModel viewModel = new MenuViewModel();
    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }



}
```

Code in viewmodel.cs

```
 public class MenuViewModel :BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Command LoadElements { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Meni> MeniElementi { get; set; }
        public MenuViewModel()
        {

            LoadElements= new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteElements());
            MeniElementi = new ObservableCollection<Meni>() {

            new Meni(){Title="Transatcions" ,Picture="xxx"},
            new Meni(){Title="Transatcions" ,Picture="xxx"},
       };
        }
        async Task ExecuteElements()
        {
            try
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new InfoPage());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {     
            }
        }
```

LoadElements Command not fired. Loading starting menu , showing menu elements just command not working to navigate to another page. Using Xamarin.Forms.Command. On other pages working normal with Command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reset the binding path of the tap . So that you can handle the logic in the same command .

#### in the ContentPage (which contains the CollectionView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="Page"   //set the name of page
             x:Class="xxx.xxxPage">
```

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page},Path=BindingContext.LoadElements}"
```

Comment: i added random name ex.Refresh on both place and now working

Comment: i have just one more question. Because this is menu how in the ViewModel with this command in ```async Task ExecuteElements()``` navigate to new Page depending on Menu item (Image) clicked?

Comment: You could use MessagingCenter to send message from ViewModel to ContentPage in the command . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: I'm little lost . Where to subscribe, where to send and what? Send the Title and based on the title move to choosen page or ?

Comment: should i open new question?

Comment: OK , I will check it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769664/xamarin-forms-tapgesturerecognizer-with-command-navigate-to-page-based-on-image

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the command on the ViewModel of the Page for that you need to do this:-

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LoadElements, Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

And put `x:Name="ThisPage"` in the ContentPage tag of the xaml at the top of the page.

Let me know if you face difficulties.

Comment: i cant understand which page to add?

Comment: You need to edit the code that you have provided. And x:Name="ThisPage" needs to be added to the same ContentPage